# Trying to test posprinting program using nonpos printer

Tags: c#, .net, point-of-sale

Im creating a pos receipt program. Right now we dont have a pos printer but i want to test my code so is it possible to use a natural printer(dont know what to call it) or should i wait for the real pos printer?
Btw im using microsoft 1.12POS sdk and Brother for printer

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a normal printer unless they have an OPOS driver available, as POS for .net needs that to talk to the printer. However POS for .net contains device simulators, including a `POS Printer`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee406171%28v=winembedded.4%29.aspx#Q3